# Conditionally Stop uploading files

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I stop uploading files in the following code if any of file upload controls not containing valid Extensions? e.g. if the file in the first control contains valid extension but the second one's extension is invalid, then I want to stop uploading files and break the operation.

```
List<string> validExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".stl" };        
for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string guidResult = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(hfc[i].FileName);
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            if (!validExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Extension not supported";

            }
            else
            {
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("files\\") + guidResult.ToString() + extension);
                lblMsg.Text = "File(s) upload successsfuly.";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: why not use the `break` keyword to break the loop whenever you fund an invalid extension? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Well you can't stop the upload itself*, the file is already on your server by this point.

Comment: I tried but still uploads file. e.g. whenever it finds a valid extension first then uploads and then for the invalid ones its displays message. if the first upload control contains invalid then stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check all before you save any of them. One example would be:

```
List<string> validExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".stl" };

if (hcf.PostedFiles.Any(x => !validExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x.FileName))))
{
     lblMsg.Text = "Extension not supported";
     return;
}    

//rest of your code here. which by the way, looks better like this:
foreach (var item in hcf.PostedFiles)
{
   string guidResult = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   item.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("files\\") + guidResult.ToString() + extension);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add a `break` statement into the code, as so:

```
....
if (!validExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Extension not supported";
    break;
}
....
```

Comment: I tried but still uploads file. e.g. whenever it finds a valid extension first then uploads and then for the invalid ones its displays message. if the first upload control contains invalid then stops.